# Importing EndNote .enl file into R Dataframe

Tags: r, rest, data-import

I would appreciate it if someone can help me import [this EndNote .enl file](https://www.dur.ac.uk/resources/its/info/guides/files/endnote/PALEO~1.ENL) into R Dataframe.

Comment: endnote .enl is a proprietary format, and notoriously difficult to do anything with outside endnote. I suggest you open th library in endnote, and then use the endnote export function to convert to ris, xml or bibtex format.  There are plenty of web tutorials that will show you how. These will be easier to import to R.

Comment: @dww thanks dww, what about the  RSServices API from EndNote. On their website, http://community.thomsonreuters.com/t5/EndNote-API/The-EndNote-RSServices-API-is-now-available/td-p/13881 they do mention that this API allows integrating with other tools.

Answer (score 4):

When I came across this issue I tried a number of different packages, including `bibliometrix` (which is a very extensive package but a bit too complicated for this task I thought), `bibtex` and `RISmed`, without success.

But then I found the `RefManageR` package which worked great for this.

I first exported the Endnote library to Bibtex, there are pretty good directions for that step at:
https://libguides.usask.ca/c.php?g=218034&p=1458583

Then I imported the file that I had just creating using the following code in R:

```
# Basic importing of BibTex files
library(RefManageR)

# User RefManageR to import bibtex references and convert to tibble
bib = ReadBib("MyEndnoteBibtexExportFile.bibtex")
d.bibEQL  = as.data.frame(bibEQL)
```

(I wanted a data frame for some custom analysis and plotting, seems like once you are here you are flexible to do whatever you want with the data, since it's just a a standard R data structure. RefManageR also has functions for further processing if that's what you want.)